# Arreglos en Javascript con numeros

Tags: javascript

vengo del lenguaje Java y estoy aprendiendo Javascript. Regularmente al iniciar un arreglo lo declaraba de forma normal `int array[]`, y lo llenaba con un `for(int i=0 i<X; i++)`

solo que al hacer esto al dar hacer el `console.log` del arreglo me da `NaN`. me parece algo extraño

tengo entendido que los arreglos pueden ser objetos pero, en este caso no se porque no detecta que el valor de i en el for es un numero y quiero que los guarde en el arreglo, de X cantidad, pero me da NaN, espero alguien me pueda ayudar, estoy aprendiendo.

Les dejo mi código

```js
const arreglo=new Array(5);
const x=5;
for(let i=0; i<x; i++){
    arreglo[i]+=i+1;

console.log(arreglo[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que los valores del array no han sido inicializados.  Puedes solucionarlo facilmente cambiando el `+=` a `=` asi:

```js
const arreglo=new Array(5);

const x=5;
for(let i=0; i<x; i++){
    arreglo[i]=i+1;

console.log(arreglo[i]);
}
```

Comment: oooh, muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

Vienes de Java y fallaste en la cosa más Java del mundo. :P Inicializar las variables pa no terminar con un NullPointerException o cosas así

Entendería que el problema está en que no se inicializa nunca el contenido de las posiciones y tu asignación es `+=`. Es decir, le sumas al contenido actual de la posición, el cálculo que haces. Y [por definición (siguiendo la documentación de MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array), el contenido es *Undefined* para un arreglo recién definido usando el constructor.

Entonces, esto funciona:

```js
    let arreglo = [0,0,0,0,0];
    const x = 5;
    for(let i=0; i < x; i++){
        arreglo[i] += i+1;
        console.log(arreglo[i]);
    }
```

O, si quieres definir sólo el tamaño, puedes probar simplificando la asignación (que igual, nunca le asignas más de una vez a cada posición, no necesitas "sumar" según parece.

```js
    let arreglo = new Array(5);
    const x = 5;
    for(let i=0; i < x; i++){
        arreglo[i] = i+1;
        console.log(arreglo[i]);
    }
```

Comment: también puedes usar `new Array(5).fill(0)`

Comment: @Fedex7501 ya aprendí algo nuevo hoy :)